# Поменять порядок вывода attachment в wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, html5

Сайт на WP, есть страница с изображениями, они выводятся в порядке их прикрепления к странице. Не получается поменять вручную их местам (важен порядок вывода на страницу), ни через базу данных (менял время загрузки, позиция меняется, но пропадает само изображение) ни через консоль.

Код вывода attachment на страницу:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="masonry-container">
            <?php $args = array(
                'order'          => 'ASC',
                'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
                'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'post_status'    => null,
                'numberposts'    => -1
            );
            $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if ($attachments) {
                foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($attachment->ID, full);
                    $img_caption = wp_get_attachment_caption($attachment->ID);
                    ?>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <a href="<?php echo $img_url; ?>"></a>
                            <div class="panel-wrapper">
                                <div class="panel-overlay">
                                    <div class="panel-text">
                                        <div class="panel-title"><?php echo $img_caption; ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="img_cont">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" alt=""/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <?php
                }
            }
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: какой порядок нужен?

Comment: нужен способ, скажем чтобы поменять несколько изображений в середине всего списка выводимых на страницу

Comment: `$attachments` - это и есть "список" изображений, что конкретно надо сделать?

Comment: например я прикрепил их в порядке от 1 до 5, а потом возникла необходимость поменять местами 1 3 5 4 2